# Laravel Validation on Array Item

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I am trying to achieve validation on Pickings Array where the location is unique,

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "type": "picking",
  "pickings": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "warehouse_id": 10,
      "type": "mobile",
      "location": "testing",
      "created_at": "2023-07-12T03:29:06.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-07-12T03:29:06.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "warehouse_id": 10,
      "type": "fixed",
      "location": "testing 1",
      "created_at": "2023-07-12T03:29:06.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-07-12T03:29:06.000000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my request class I am using this code

```
public function rules()
{
return [
        'pickings.*.location' => [
                    Rule::unique('warehouse_pickings')
                        ->where('warehouse_id', $this->input('id'))
                        ->ignore($this->input('pickings.*.id'), 'id')
                ]
       ];
}
```

But I am having error

```
exception
: 
"TypeError"
file
: 
"/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/php/ash/tag/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Unique.php"
line
: 
70
message
: 
"addslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given"
```

So far I think I need the exact value of `$this->input('pickings.*.id')`. So how can I get the value of `*`, the index value its testing.

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered with **addslashes()** indicates that the **Rule::unique()** method expects a string as the first argument, but it received an array instead. The reason for this issue is that the **ignore()** method should be called outside the validation rules, not within the array syntax. Let's fix the validation code:

Assuming you have a **WarehousePicking** model for the "warehouse_pickings" table, you can use the **unique** rule and **where** clause to enforce uniqueness based on the "location" field while ignoring specific records (if they exist) during updates.

```
$data = []
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'pickings' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'pickings.*.location' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('warehouse_pickings', 'location')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->where('warehouse_id', $data['id']);
            })
            ->ignore(function ($value, $key) use ($data) {
                // Ignore the 'pickings.*.id' values for the update scenario
                if (isset($data['pickings'][$key]['id'])) {
                    return $data['pickings'][$key]['id'];
                }
                return null;
            }, 'id')
    ],
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Validation failed
    $errors = $validator->errors();
    // Handle errors here
} else {
    // Validation succeeded
    // Process the data
}
```